# Is it possible to track In-App billing with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've developed the app, which have In-app purchase using payment gateway system.
(Third-party payment system.)

and I tried to insert Google Analytics in the App, BUT, I have a question.

**Is it possible to track In-app billing info. through Google Analytics ?
If possible, What sort of details can be shown in GA ?**

Thank you in advance, and Have a nice day. :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/ecommerce ?